# TopLink JPA EntityManager flush and Oracle on update trigger

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, triggers, toplink

We have one table Product in Oracle database which is having two triggers on it only for auditing purpose (legacy implementation).

1. For insert or update
2. on Update

Sometimes when we are merging an entity for an update of this table. it stuck at flushing and it consumes time ~2-3 seconds. This behaviors we can not produce in development environment and we are not much sure what is causing this delay. Before we have not placed EntityManager.flush() so flush mode was auto. But it was getting blocked on any subsequent select statement. Then we tried to add flush at the time of merge itself.

```
public class ProductDAO{
     private EnitiyManager em;
     public void updateProduct(ProductDTO productDTO){
         Product product = em.findById(Product.class, productDTO.getId());
         product.setModifiedDate(new Date());
         long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
         em.merge(product);
         em.flush(); // This call get blocked by DB
         System.out.println("Time taken (ms): " + (start - System.currentTimeMillis());
     }
}
```

The generated SQL for this update is very simple and we are struggling to find out what is causing this much delay.

```
UPDATE PRODUCT SET MODIFIED_DATE = ? WHERE PRODUCT_ID = ?
```

Environment Details

- JPA 2
- Toplink
- Oracle
- 3.5 million records in PRODUCT table

**Issue is resolved** as the trigger was doing some table scan based on user who is modifying the Product. PL/SQL fix resolved this issue.

Comment: Question: How many tuples are stored in table `Product` of the production database (roughly speaking)?

Comment: This is happening in production as well in UAT. But production is consuming more time till ~3-9 seconds. No of records are around 3 million.

Comment: That is why I asked: „How many“ tuples exist for this table in the production environment? Roughly 3 million is quite some volume to process in terms of disk IO.

Comment: But we are updating the row with primary key. This behavior is not consistent some time same update is happening in 20 mili seconds.

Comment: By PK, I see. Still, it‘s a different situation depending on DB internal optimizations, e.g. memory for buffers etc., and/or query execution plans. Even load of the DB and the OS is a topic. Tracking it down requires more information which only you and your team might have.

Comment: We are trying to find the root cause for this issue. My concern is on triggers are causing the delay at the time update is happening when data is flushed.

Comment: Enable trancing for this single UPDATE command (see: [Tracing Individual SQL Statements](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof#tracing_individual_sql_statements)), collect trace files for some time, analyze them.

Comment: Thank you @krokodilko for suggesting for individual tracing. I will do enable the same to check issue in detail.

Comment: @krokodilko i have tried to follow provided steps in the Tracing Individual SQL. But the file is not being generated in oracle.